# Apache proxy reverse to webmin (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, reverse-proxy, webmin

I have a CentOS7 virtualized in my testing homelab. I installed webmin along with Apache webserver and I can reach the webmin login page through the CentOS machine IP address on port 10000 (https).
Now, I would like to setup an A record within my DNS server to point directly to webmin console.
I read much this evening about Apache reverse proxy, I understand it does fit my needs but I could not figured out how working properly.
I installed `mod_ssl`, created a Key and a Certificate files by `openssl`.
Then, filled in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file enabling a virtual host with these settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName webmin.domain.loc

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/CA-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/CA-selfsigned.key
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / https://[machine_ip]:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://[machine_ip]:10000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I browse `https://webmin.domain.loc` it point to the classic Apache HTTP Server Test Page 1,2,3... (you know?)

[image: t]

The only way to access login page is `https://webmin.domain.loc:10000`, so as far as I know it does not work as intended.
Which settings are wrong or missing?

I am very confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Webmin has a page about how to do it, and why (in their opinion) it's a bad idea. Check it out by yourself at [Webmin/Running_Webmin_Under_Apache](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Running_Webmin_Under_Apache)